# Spring Security With Restlet?

Tags: spring, security, restlet

> HI ,
>
> I would Like Know whether there is a good way to integrate spring and
>   restlet  . I want secure the API's with spring security . I want to
>   know configurations needed (web.xml,spring-security.xml like that and
>   other) . Please  help me . It will be more helpful.

Comment: If you not stick to spring, then I prefere apache Shiro. http://shiro.apache.org/

Comment: What do you mean by good way? Do you have spring security for your application already developed? Some tips can help to secure your api's...but depends on how you developed your code.

Answer (score 0):

We're improving the Restlet extension for Spring at the moment by integrating the Roger Stocker's contribution.

See the following links for more details and to find out how to use the extension:

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/508
https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/816
http://code4you.org/2013/07/spring-custom-xml-namespace-scheme-for-the-restlet-framework/

Hope it helps you.
Thierry